# Find functions names in .init_array section in unstripped library

Tags: symbols, elf, objdump, static-initialization, readelf

Is it possible to find out all instances of static initialization in a elf dynamic library. I can dump the array of function pointers in .init_array section via objdump command like this.

```
objdump -s -j .init_array <libname.so>
```

Is there a way to map these function pointers back to function names. I have unstripped library with debug symbols. I want to eliminate static initialization as much as possible to improve my library load time.

Comment: Even if you could identify any functions that are called from the `.init_array`,
they would not necessarily be all the instances of static initialization in the DSO.
See [How to count static initializer in an ELF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15532590/1362568)

Comment: That's okay, I can do the same thing for .init and .ctors sections as well. But is there a way to find out function names from function pointers?

Answer (score 3):

On x86-64, `.init_array` contains a list of 8-byte little-endian pointers to static initializers/constructors. The example below has 4 initializers with the addresses - `0x1160`, `0x11a7`, `0x1231` and `0x12bb`:

```
$ objdump -s -j .init_array a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .init_array:
 3d88 60110000 00000000 a7110000 00000000  `...............
 3d98 31120000 00000000 bb120000 00000000  1...............
```

You can find the initializer function by providing an address from `.init_array` to `objdump`. E.g. the address `0x11a7` points to the special function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_a` (static initializer for the global variable `a`):

```
$ objdump -S --start-address=0x11a7 a.out | head

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000011a7 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_a>:
    11a7:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    11ab:       55                      push   %rbp
    11ac:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
```